# Laravel - Array to string conversion error on Model::create or Model->save()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm performing a simple insert which I've done many times without any issues and for some odd reason it's not working and I get this error message:

```
error: {type: "ErrorException", message: "Array to string conversion",…}
file: "C:\wamp\www\studentreg2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Grammar.php"
  line: 33
  message: "Array to string conversion"
  type: "ErrorException"
```

Here's my code:

```
$advisorCheck = AdvisorCheck::create([
            'status'         => Input::get('status'),
            'application_id' => Input::get('id'),
            'user_id'        => Auth::id()
        ]);
```

The migration for the advisor_check table which AdvisorCheck model uses seems fine, all foreign keys are unsigned and show the relations correctly in phpmyadmin, all values from the Input::get are strings, the model has the correct fields set as fillable (status, application_id, user_id).

I've even tried doing this in `php artisan tinker` like this:

```
AdvisorCheck::create([ 'status' => 'returned', 'application_id' => '3', 'user_id' => '4']);
```

and I get this response:
Array to string conversion

I've also tried this method and get the same error:

```
$advisorCheck                 = new AdvisorCheck;
$advisorCheck->status         = Input::get('status');
$advisorCheck->application_id = Input::get('id');
$advisorCheck->user_id        = Auth::id();
$advisorCheck->save();
```

Model code:

```
<?php

class AdvisorCheck extends \Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = ['status', 'application_id', 'user_id'];

    protected $table = ['advisor_check'];
}
```

If you need to see more code please ask.

Many thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: Is there anything out of the ordinary in the Model?

Comment: I've got a feeling it's because I put the $table before $fillable, all my other models have $fillable first - giving it a shot now

Comment: Nope wasn't it - didn't make any sense for it to be that I guess? I'll post the model code

Comment: What happens if you just put fixed strings and try to save the model? (rather than using Input::get just put a random string in)

Comment: See in the question, I tried that using `php artisan tinker` for the model::create() it shows the same error `Array to string conversion` I'll give it a shot in the code as well and with the model->save() approach too

Comment: The `table` property needs to be a string not an array!

Comment: @lukasgeiter Good spot.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I feel so silly... serves me right for trying to rush things!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As you can see in the example that's shown in the [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#basic-usage) the table property is a **string** and not an array

```
protected $table = 'advisor_check';
```

Which makes total sense if you think about it, since Eloquent models don't support multiple tables natively.

Answer (score 2):

`$table` should be a string not array

```
<?php

   class AdvisorCheck extends \Eloquent {

   protected $fillable = ['status', 'application_id', 'user_id'];

   protected $table = 'advisor_check';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if we give table name in laravel model like array:

```
 protected $table = ['thoughts'];
```

then it will generate error.

so you should give table name as string like :

```
protected $table = 'thoughts';
```